# Update Case Contact via API call, not working

Tags: api, case, contact

How do I set the Case Contact fields via the API?
When I create a case in salesforce via the API. I have no issues creating it, except that the Contact Name/Email/Phone isn't being populated. I used the following to POST to create the Case.

```
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/sobjects/Case/
```

When I try and pull the case from the API it doesn't have a field for it either. See below of a view of the case created in salesforce.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't have access to the Contact objects that was preventing me from adding ContactId to my payload to create a case. Also Origin was missing from the payload.